# Retrieving additional properties from JNDI custom-resource

Tags: java, glassfish, jndi, mbeans

I have this JNDI custom-resource configured on my Glassfish server:

[image]

I also have a web application deployed, and at some point, I want to get the value configured for the "version" additional property of my custom-resource.

My factory class is like that:

```
public class TestCRFactory implements ObjectFactory {

    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable<?, ?> environment) {
        if (obj instanceof Reference) {
            Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
            Enumeration<RefAddr> addrs = ref.getAll();
            while (addrs.hasMoreElements()) {
                RefAddr addr = addrs.nextElement();
                if (addr.getType().equals("version")) {
                    String version = (String) addr.getContent();
                    System.out.println(version); // it shows me "1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I lookup the object:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
Object obj = context.lookup("test/TestCR");
```

My code works, and I can get the "version" property in the factory class with no problem.

But now I want to get the "version" property without lookup the object and invoke the factory class. I just want to do something like that, via MBeanServer:

```
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import javax.management.ObjectName;

...
boolean existsObject = false;
String name = "amx:pp=/domain/resources,type=custom-resource,name=test/TestCR";
ObjectName objName = new ObjectName(name);
try {
    MBeanServer mbean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    existsObject = mbean.getObjectInstance(objName) != null; // this line works
    if (existsObject) {
       Object attr = mbean.getAttribute(objName, "version"); // this line doesn't work. it doesn't give me the "version" property I want.
    }
} catch (Throwable e) {
    existsObject = false;
}
```

My question is: what am I doing wrong? Should I put the property name at the end of `name` variable? Or something like that?

Comment: I do not see any `JNDI`-related stuff here.  Please show it.  Also please describe the exact problem you're facing.

Comment: @PM77-1 I think now I put in a better way.

Comment: +1 for **excellent** description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it!

Just using the `getAttribute` method like this:

```
getAttribute("amx:pp=/domain/resources/custom-resource[test/TestCR],type=property,name=version", "Value");
```

So my final code was:

```
boolean existsObject = false;
ObjectName objName = new ObjectName("amx:pp=/domain/resources,type=custom-resource,name=test/TestCR");
try {
    MBeanServer mbean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    existsObject = mbean.getObjectInstance(objName) != null;
    if (existsObject) {
       Object attr = mbean.getAttribute("amx:pp=/domain/resources/custom-resource[test/TestCR],type=property,name=version", "Value");
       // here 'attr' var is indicating '1', as I've set! (I tested with other values too) 
    }
} catch (Throwable e) {
    existsObject = false;
}
```